# Pull an object from array if the objects parameter is an array

Tags: mongodb

Were using Mongodb CLI to pull an object from array if the objects that have parameter that is an Array.

We have documents in our collection that looks like this :

```
{
    "websites": [
        {
            "website": "http: //google.com"
        },
        {
            "website": []
        }
    ]
}
```

And we are trying to `pull` the website objects in the  websites object array that contain an array.

We have tried :

```
 db.influencer2.update({
   'websites.website': []
 }, {
   $pull: {
     'websites.$.website': []
   }
 }, {
   multi: true,
 });
```

and received

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 31657, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

Which means the documents have been matched but not modified.
We need the objects modified.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$elemMatch` you find nested array matching fields and then use `$pull` method. Check following query which remove all empty website array

```
db.collectionName.update({
  "websites": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "website": []
    }
  }
}, {
  "$pull": {
    "websites": {
      "website": []
    }
  }
}, false, true)
```